# Header background isn't showing up since adding a background image

Tags: html, css

I had a header with background color already set. Then I added a background-image to the page and suddenly, my header background isn't showing up. The words are still there and visible but the box of color has become invisible. It's something to do with the background-image because if I remove the image the box reappears. I can post code if needed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: "if needed"? unless you think that we're psychic and can see through your eyes, exactly how else do you expect us to be able to help you?

Comment: Hey @seth, you should always post relevant code and set up an example in a http://jsFiddle.net :)

Comment: It is probably to do with the syntax you used for the background. You say you saw a background color, but since you added the image you don't see it anymore. Show the css.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I'm new to this site. 
So I figured out where I went wrong. I had posted the img under * in css. I feel pretty silly when I realized it. I fixed it by adding

```
body
{
   background:url("example.jpg")
}
```

Worked like a charm. Thanks for the help everyone.